# "Must specify limits.cpu" error during pod deployment even though cpu limit is specified

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

I am trying to run a test pod with OpenShift CLI:

```
$oc run nginx --image=nginx --limits=cpu=2,memory=4Gi
deploymentconfig.apps.openshift.io/nginx created

$oc describe deploymentconfig.apps.openshift.io/nginx
Name:       nginx
Namespace:  myproject
Created:    12 seconds ago
Labels:     run=nginx
Annotations:    <none>
Latest Version: 1
Selector:   run=nginx
Replicas:   1
Triggers:   Config
Strategy:   Rolling
Template:
Pod Template:
  Labels:   run=nginx
  Containers:
   nginx:
    Image:  nginx
    Port:   <none>
    Host Port:  <none>
    Limits:
      cpu:      2
      memory:       4Gi
    Environment:    <none>
    Mounts:     <none>
  Volumes:      <none>

Deployment #1 (latest):
    Name:       nginx-1
    Created:    12 seconds ago
    Status:     New
    Replicas:   0 current / 0 desired
    Selector:   deployment=nginx-1,deploymentconfig=nginx,run=nginx
    Labels:     openshift.io/deployment-config.name=nginx,run=nginx
    Pods Status:    0 Running / 0 Waiting / 0 Succeeded / 0 Failed

Events:
  Type      Reason          Age         From                Message
  ----      ------          ----            ----                -------
  Normal    DeploymentCreated   12s         deploymentconfig-controller Created new replication controller "nginx-1" for version 1
  Warning   FailedCreate        1s (x12 over 12s)   deployer-controller     Error creating deployer pod: pods "nginx-1-deploy" is forbidden: failed quota: quota-svc-myproject: must specify limits.cpu,limits.memory
```

I get "must specify limits.cpu,limits.memory" error, despite both limits being present in the same **describe** output.

What might be the problem and how do I fix it?

Comment: Not an OpenShift person here but have you tried setting a "Requests" as well?

Comment: Yes, I tried, it didn't help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found a solution!

Part of the error message was "Error creating deployer pod". It means that the problem is not with my pod, but with the **deployer pod** which performs my pod deployment.
It seems the quota in my project affects deployer pods as well.
I couldn't find a way to set deployer pod limits with CLI, so I've made a DeploymentConfig.

```
kind: "DeploymentConfig"
apiVersion: "v1"
metadata:
  name: "test-app"
spec:
  template: 
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: "test-app"
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: "test-app"
          image: "nginxinc/nginx-unprivileged"
          resources:
            limits:
              cpu: "2000m"
              memory: "20Gi"
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
              protocol: "TCP"
  replicas: 1 
  selector:
    name: "test-app"
  triggers:
    - type: "ConfigChange" 
    - type: "ImageChange" 
      imageChangeParams:
        automatic: true
        containerNames:
          - "test-app"
        from:
          kind: "ImageStreamTag"
          name: "nginx-unprivileged:latest"
  strategy: 
    type: "Rolling"
    resources:
      limits:
        cpu: "2000m"
        memory: "20Gi"
```

A you can see, two sets of limitations are specified here: for container and for deployment strategy.

With this configuration it worked fine!

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you have specified resource quota and the values you specified for limits seems to be larger than that. Can you describe the resource quota `oc describe quota quota-svc-myproject` and adjust your configs accordingly.

A good reference could be https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/dev_guide/compute_resources.html

Comment: In addition to the above, please review the `scopes` defined in the `ResourceQuota`. If there is no scope set, deployer Pods may not be able to be deployed. See [the documentation](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/admin_guide/quota.html#quota-scopes), what you typically want to have defined is "NotTerminating".

Comment: I am also having same issue but I am using helm chart so looking for sample reference / documents with example how limitsMemory and requestsMemory are managed in helm charts for cronjob

Answer (score 0):

In my case I saw similar error once I have added resource quota to namespace. It looks like quota must be set to container if namespace has quota setting.

I solved this issue by adding quota when creating deployment from python API:

```
resQuota = kube.client.V1ResourceRequirements()
resQuota.limits = {"cpu": "1000m"}

container = kube.client.V1Container(name='your_name', image='your_image', env=envList, resources=resQuota, stdin=True, tty=True)
```